# How to convert physical machine to virtual machine

Tags: server, vmware

Im having a ubuntu physical server with 18.04LTS OS having a 500gb of Data,
now i want convert this physical machine to virtual machine in VMWARE environment,
I have tried using VMware converter but its throwing an error, even i have tried with DD command and as well startwind but no luck,
can any one suggest any better way to convert

VMware version -8

Comment: Ubuntu 18.04 is EOSS (*end-of-standard-support*) thus off-topic on this site (refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic) unless your question is specifically about moving to a *fully supported* release of Ubuntu. Being EOSS, mirrors can drop the release.  Refer https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades  https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2023/06/17/extended-security-maintenance-for-ubuntu-18-04-lts-began-on-may-31-2023/

Comment: 18.04 is EOS, i have some supported builds in this and also created some local repo's, 
so i like to keep it live for some more days,

Comment: Ubuntu 18.04 ESM is available (*refer link I provided in first comment, support options are available for ESM too*) but it's now **off-topic** on this site. SE *Unix & Linux* allows all Unix & Linux questions (*including EOL/ESM & development release of Ubuntu that are off-topic here; read first comment links*) but your question isn't on-topic for this site. Please re-read first comment.